# VIM: Reformat all brackets, parens and block brackets equally

Tags: regex, vim, formatting

I'm searching for a way have some random text like this

```
[a: b -> {a, b, c}, d<1, 2>, b: [2, 3], (a, b)]
```

reformatted to something better readable, for example:

```
[
    a: b -> {
        a,
        b,
        c
    },
    d<1, 2>,
    b: [
        2,
        3
    ],
    (
        a,
        b
    )
]
```

Is anybody aware of some way to reformat text with brackets similar to the example? It's not important, that the format looks exactly as above, it's just for readability (the texts are much longer than `a`, `b` or `c`).

Currently, I'm using this mapping:

```
%j<CR>:%s/[\[{]\\|[\]}],\\|,/&\r/g<CR>gg=Ggg:nohls<CR>
```

This works not very well and requires some extra cleanup.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a general-purpose way of splitting generic text into multiline components like you describe. I do have a plugin called [splitjoin](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/splitjoin.vim) that tries to do something like that, but it works for specific constructs in specific programming languages. For example, [lists and tuples in python](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/splitjoin.vim/blob/7ee9377201a29b8c1f5098cda7fb2432c376d8ad/doc/splitjoin.txt#L354-L369). If you look at the full help file, you might find that it works for you, but I can't say for sure. It might be possible for you to re-use some of the [splitting and joining functions](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/splitjoin.vim/blob/7ee9377201a29b8c1f5098cda7fb2432c376d8ad/ftplugin/python/splitjoin.vim) directly.

Another plugin of mine that might help is [sideways](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/sideways.vim), because it provides a text object for arguments in a list (which you can visually select and operate on afterwards). In my experiments, though, it doesn't seem to detect `d<1, 2>` right, so you might have to create [your own list definition](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/sideways.vim/blob/4e63889779a41c74e820675769890b1b9cc88f9f/plugin/sideways.vim#L17-L22) that detects `<>` brackets (I wouldn't put that in the general plugin, because of `1 < 2` and such). Unfortunately, even then, it gets confused by the `->` before that. If you have *all* of these in the same list, I don't think this plugin can help.

This isn't much of a solution, just a direction, I suppose. If this is code of a particular programming language, it might help to specify which one it is.

Comment: I tried splitjoin and had a look at sideways. Splitjoin seems to do something like that, but it doesn't seem to work correctly when I select callbacks from different language plugins. In general I do think, that a plugin is not required for this problem. I just found the genindent plugin, which seems to be suitable. I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something similar to this:

`:%s/\(\[\|{\|(\|,\)\|\(<.\{-}>,\)\|\(}\|]\|)\)/\1\2\r\3/g`

`=gg`

**OUTPUT**

```
[
    a: b -> {
            a,
                b,
                c
    },
    d<1, 2>, 
    b: [
        2,
        3
    ],
    (
     a,
     b
     )
]
```